# How to create datefield in django models in the format (mm-dd-yyyy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, date-format

I'm scraping the dates from different websites and it is in the format of `mm-dd-yyyy` ie. `10-28-2021`. Right now, I'm storing it as a string.

In django models, I have created the field as:

```py
issued = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

This stores the date as string.

But I want to convert into a datefield.

When I tried:

```py
issued = models.DateField()
```

I cannot store the date in this field.

How to add the date in the particular format in the above field?

After solution,

The Traceback is :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['grappelli',
 'filebrowser',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dibbs_spider',
 'userapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\spider\templates\Partsbase-data-table (1).html, error at line 295
   month must be in 1..12
   285 :                            <th>Issued</th>
   286 :                            <th>Return by</th>
   287 : <!--                           <th>Est. Value</th>-->
   288 : <!--                           <th>Days</th>-->
   289 : <!--                           <th>Status</th>-->
   290 : <!--                           <th>Match Details</th>-->
   291 :                            <th>Download</th>
   292 :                        </tr>           
   293 :                    </thead>
   294 :                    <tbody>
   295 :                         {% for i in dibbs %} 
   296 :                        <tr>
   297 :                            <!-- <td data-label="#">{{ i.hash}}</td> -->
   298 :                            <td data-label="NSN/Part Number">{{ i.nsn }}</td>
   299 :                            <td data-label="Nomenclature">{{ i.nomenclature }}</td>
   300 :                            <td data-label="Technical Documents">{{ i.technical_documents }}</td>
   301 :                            <td data-label="solicitation">{{ i.solicitation }}</td>
   302 :                            <td data-label="status">{{ i.status }}</td>
   303 :                            <td data-label="purchase_request">{{ i.purchase_request }}</td>
   304 :                            <td data-label="issued">{{ i.issued|date:"m-d-Y" }}</td>
   305 :                            <td data-label="Return by">{{ i.return_by|date:"m-d-Y" }}</td>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\spider\dibbs_spider\views.py", line 25, in bids
    return render(request,'Partsbase-data-table (1).html',context)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 143, in __len__
    return len(self.object_list)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 64, in convert_date
    return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: month must be in 1..12
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot store the data? Do you mean that when you try to store a date it throws an error?

Comment: yes it means date

Comment: I've just posted an answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string into Date time object using strptime,

```
from datetime import datetime    
date_time_str = '10-28-2021'

date1 = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%m-%d-%Y")
print(date1)
```

**EDIT1 :**
If you want it without the time ,

```
from datetime import datetime    
date_time_str = '10-28-2021'

date1 = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%m-%d-%Y").date()
print(type(date1))
```

Comment: Also shows the time which is not needed.

Comment: just parse it into a date type... adding it in edit

Answer (score 3):

You can change input format of date in `settings.py` like this:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%m-%d-%Y']
```

Here's official Django doc: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)

Comment: ValueError at /
month must be in 1..12

Comment: Could you provide full error?

Comment: @AtomStore And please show us your code where you try to save the date to the database.

Comment: It doesn't show error while saving to the database

Comment: But shows while running the site

Comment: @AtomStore. Oh, then please show the relevant code.

Comment: added the traceback

Comment: Please show me the code as well.

Comment: which code, there is nothing error in code, the data is being stored but while running it shows the error

Comment: The error says that month must be 1 through 12. So please show me your code that saves the date. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you changed the format of the date.

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to bed. I'm in Chicago. But no worries, I'll come back and help.

Comment: please refer to the answer of @SANGEETH SUBRAMONIAM. Maybe his answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) and set [USE_L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-USE_L10N) `False` to change the date format of [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) and [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) as shown below. *`USE_L10N` is prior to `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` so you need to set `USE_L10N` `False` and you can see the default settings of [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/global_settings.py#L376):

```py
# "settings.py"

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%m-%d-%Y'] # '10-28-2021'

USE_L10N = False # Here
```

The doc says below in [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)

> When `USE_L10N` is `True`, the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied instead.